# Bootstrap modal not working in datatable row

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I want to use bootstrap modal in yejra datatable. when i click on open modal its pop up. Here modal works fine if I not call it from datatable. Here is my code. I am using laravel 5.6

```
return DataTables::of($users_data)
         ->addColumn('action', function ($users_data) use ($condition) {
           return '<button type="button" class="myBtn btn btn-info btn-lg" id="">Open Modal</button>'
```

modal// here I just keep first line of modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

Comment: how is it put on the dom? is it encoded html? what's not working and whats the errors?

Comment: no error shows in console

Comment: 1 down... how is it put on the dom? is it encoded html? what's not working?

Comment: most likely `return DataTables...` htmlentities the html you're trying to insert and/or the response is done though ajax and you dont re-attach the event handler on the buttons.

Comment: not encoded.... function getdata()
    {
        $condition = "12";
       $users_data = test::where('flag','Y')
                       ->get(['id','name','email','phone']);
       return DataTables::of($users_data)
                          ->addColumn('action', function ($users_data) use ($condition) {
                            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button> 
                            ';

          })
       ->make(true);
    }

Comment: must be the event handlers then.. maybe change code to `$(document).on('click', '.myBtn',`

Comment: Thanks..... it's working

Answer (score 1):

try this if you have multiple modal just pass dynamic modal value to the function
**HTML**

```
var modal='moadal1';
    <button type="button" class="myBtn btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="someFunction('+modal+')">Open Modal 1</button>
```

**js**

```
function someFunction(val){
  $(val).modal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also do this by help of adding a class and with help of class get the id and which is combination of row id included . it is very important to get data of each row .
Now access model with the help of model id**

```
return DataTables::of($users_data)
     ->addColumn('action', function ($users_data) use ($condition) {
       return `<button type="button" 
       class="myBtn btn btn-info btn-lg"  
       id="ModelID${rowID}>Open Modal</button>`;

       $('.myBtn').click(function(function(){
           var modal_id='#'+$(this).attr('id');
           $(modal_id).modal('show');

     }));
```